# How to start Hangouts from Glassware

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I want to start Hangouts from my Glassware so that the user can make video call to any of his contacts in the Glass. I tried the giving the package name of the hangout app in an intent , but it did not work. If anybody has tried this before ,please do share.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Starting a hangout from an intent isn't supported by the GDK. A feature request was filed in our issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=252); feel free to follow it so that you can be updated if anything changes!

Answer (score -3):

I want to start Hangouts from my Glassware so that team can see what is out put is coming.

I did lots of RnD, then I come up with below solution

steps -

1. install myglass  into mobile
2. install your apps in google glass
3. paired with glass with your mobile thr Bluetooth
4. start myglass apps and sync with glass

done

now start you application over the google glass, it will show at mobile in same way and behavior.

let me know if it work